# Shut down ZeroMQ receiving end without loss

Tags: zeromq

I am developing a (Python/pyzmq)) ZeroMQ server that receives incoming messaging through a PULL socket.

Now, there will be times when I will make a clean restart of the server to upgrade it. My question is; **Can I somehow stop receiving incoming messages (on my PULL socket) so that a restart does not loose any messages?** I am thinking of something like calling `close()` no the socket, and then `recv()`ing the last message. Possibly setting high water mark to zero would yield a similar result.

If none of the above solutions works, I might be better off converting my socket to a REP socket and fetch each message on by one, ACK:ing them every time. Since this would be synchronous, I guess this would be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using clrzmq with ZMQ 3.2.2 and I got the above functionality by setting the following properties on the PULL socket:

1. Setting the receive high watermark on the pull socket to the number of msgs I'm willing to keep in memory.
2. Setting the buffer size to the appropriate size.
3. When I no longer wish to receive messages I call socket.disconnect() on the receiving channel.

After disconnect, the channel will no longer get new msgs. If you set the high watermark on the sender side it will start keeping the msgs in the sender queue (So that events will not get lost)

When channel is disconnected, calling receive events will succeed while there are msgs in the receiver queue. I'm using receive with a timeout so if it fails after the timeout, when the channel is disconnected, I'm assuming the queue is empty and I can dispose the channel and restart the service.
When the service is back up all msgs stored in the sender queue will get dispatched.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, 0mq wont offer such type of reliable delivery itself. You should use scheme with ACK's for sure.

See [Chapter Four - Reliable Request-Reply](http://zguide2.zeromq.org/py%3aall#toc65) of zguide.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's funny though that a close on the sender makes sure to empty all queue, but something like that does not exist on the receiving end...